# Convert word to double word in assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, coding-style

I'm having some problems trying to solve this expression in assembler.

```
`$`z=(5*a-b/7)/(3/b+a*a)
```

I would like to know *how do you convert* a word to a double word ( unsigned solution ) ,
do i have to use the cwb command or do i use `AX:BX` , if i do have to use those last registers ,
 how do i properly write the command ?

I will be testing the code in Turbo Debugger under DosBox .
My full code

```
assume cs:code,ds:data 
data segment
;
a db ?
b db ?
rez dw ?
;
data ends
;
code segment
;
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
;
;
;#####prima paranteza
;
mov al,a    ;ah=a
mul 5       ;ax=a*5
mov cx,ax   ;cx=ax
mov ah,b    ; il mut pe ah in b  ( pregatire pt conversie fara semn )
mov al,0    ; l-am convertit pe b in word ( pe 2 octeti )
div 7       ; am impartit double word-ul b la 7 , catul a ramas in ah , restul a ramas in al 
sub cx,ax   ; (am tinut cont de faptul ca in ax a ramas rezultatul dupa impartire )  , cx=cx-ax, a*5 - b/7
;
; ####a 2 a paranteza
;
mov ah,3    
mov al,0    ; conversie de la b la w  ( fara semn )
div b       ; ax=3/b
mov bx,ax   ; bx = ax
mov al,a    
mul a       ; ax = a * a 
add ax,bx   ; ax = ax + bx
;
;
; #### calcul final 
mov bx,ax   ; bx = ax ( rezultatul celei de a 2 a paranteze )
mov ax,cx   ; ax = cx ( rezultatul primei paranteze )
```

Comment: Btw, I would specify which CPU architecture, even though this looks like x86 assembler

Comment: What does your specification say? In what register pair do you want to express the result? The answer is anyway just to clear the upper part. (eg. xor dx,dx)

Comment: If you have Turbo Debugger then you also have Turbo C.  Write the expression in C and look with the debugger at the generated machine code.  Next step is to then **not** convert that code but just call it.

Comment: @HansPassant homework assignments do have a points when you stick to the rules of the game. calling the code is not in the rulebook , only clasical , *learning how to code in asm intro stuff * allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

word to double-word?

Let's see if I got you:

word -> 8bit
double-word -> 16bit

AX, BX, CX and DX are 16 bit registers, and they are formed by two other 8-bit registers [ABCD]H and [ABCD]L, so, AX would be:

AH                      AL
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0| - |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|

When you use AX, you're using those two at the same time. So, if you want to convert a word to a double word, you just clear the whole [ABCD]X register, and then move your word to the [ABCD]L register, leaving [ABCD]X with the word value.

Cheers

Comment: thank you :)  , and thank all of you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the worst-case scenario would be to zero-out the double word and then copy the word to the lower part (The first 0-x bits / my assembler is rusty) of the double word. There might be a more efficient way to do this, I'll admit

Comment: There are no double words in the given architecture, so it's implementation specific, which register is considered the upper word.

Comment: @ Aki Suihkonen : the only specifications are that i have to provide a working solution for that expression .  @Joe Plante : I'm working on understanding what you just said and transposing that into ASM code , thank you .

Answer (score 0):

First, what are the range/s of the variables? Are they all unsigned (or are some of them signed)?

Second, what sort of accuracy do you need; and how does this influence things like accuracy loss due to rounding in integer divisions?

Third, how important is performance? How important is memory usage?

Fourth, what sorts of "CPU type" constraints are there? Is it "8086 only" (where you can't use 32-bit registers), or is it "80386 or later" (where you can use 32-bit registers in 16-bit code)? Can you use floating point and the FPU?

Depending on all of the above, the resulting code might look like this:

```
; Assumes a ranges from 0 to 7
; Assumes b ranges from 1 to 1234
; Assumes 80386 or later
; Note: requires a pre-computed 19728-byte lookup table

    movzx eax,word a
    movzx ebx,word b
    lea eax,[0xFFFFFFF8 + ebx*8+eax]
    mov ax,[myTable + eax*2]
```

Of course depending on all of the above the resulting code might be radically different too...

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be done with DX:AX in 16-bit mode.  You can use CWD to sign-extend AX into DX, or you could just clear DX.